# How to remove header image on subpages in Twenty Eleven (default theme)?

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-eleven

I'd like to remove the header image on all the pages except my "home"-page.

Any ideas?

Thks

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `header.php` file and modify the following lines (probably around line 78-82):

**Before**

```
        <?php
            // Check to see if the header image has been removed
            $header_image = get_header_image();
            if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
        ?>
```

**After**

```
        <?php
            // Check to see if the header image has been removed
            $header_image = get_header_image();
            if ( ! empty( $header_image ) && is_front_page() ) :
        ?>
```

Comment: Actually, I think you want to use **`is_front_page()`** rather than **`is_home()`**. The former returns true when the **site front page** is displayed, while the latter returns true when the **blog posts index** is being displayed.

Comment: @Chip Bennett Good point. Fixed.

Comment: in a child them, we can do this with template files, but can we do this in function.php file? this will be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Change

> if ( $header_image) :

to

> if ( $header_image && is_front_page()) :

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header image code from your category, post, single, etc files (leaving it in the index.php file).

If that is not of help, please explain the structure of your theme as well as post some code for additional help.

Comment: The original question specified the Twenty Eleven theme. The header image code is in the header.php file, not in all those individual files (as is probably the case in 99.9% of all themes).

Comment: no worries bro but thanks for toasting my bread.